# Hindi word not take while rendering html in canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

When I try to render Hindi word with html in canvas then I see some creches in word like below images.

https://ibb.co/MVctvRh

Here is my jquery canvas code

```
html2canvas(document.querySelector(".card-content-img")).then(canvas => {
   document.body.appendChild(canvas);
   $(canvas).attr('id', 'canvas-fab').css('display', 'none');

   var img = canvas.toDataURL({
       format: 'jpeg'
   })

});
```

And below my html code

```
<div class="card-content-img card-content-img">
    <div class="quote-img ">
        <img src="upload/image.jpeg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="over-text">
        <div class="user-text">
            <p class="center-text">
                 हिंदी शब्द
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How I do print proper Hindi word in image ? Is there issues with canvas rendering ?

Comment: I am not sure if this will make a difference but do you have <meta charset="UTF-8"> in your html?

Comment: Yes I have do that but not working @DaminiGanesh